# How to control emission, speed, velocity of particles using sound?

Tags: particles, animation-nodes

I kind of know current Blender 2.79 Particles limitation (unable to turn on and off or sending multiple burst), but I recalled in the past there was AN video that control Particles emission based on sound high and low. Can someone help me point it out or suggest how to do this?

Would that be involving multiple Particle Systems that is triggered at different time?

Comment: Particle systems are time discretized, every frame affect all the frames that are after it. And blender doesn't allow us to control the particle system in anyway. So it is practically impossible to do what you are describing. What we can do, however, is implement a new particle system in Animation Nodes and control it as we wish. Would you be interested in this?

Comment: I guess this is the answer for now, unless Blender Particles is updated to support this. It needs some AN particles.

Comment: Also, did you try disabling gravity and surface normal velocity, then add a wind force and control its strength through the *Evaluate Sound Node* and the *Object Attribute Output Node*?

Comment: That will be amazing. To get a really artist oriented particle system inside AN